# How to remap keys in the linux console? (Wayland)

Tags: terminal, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, wayland

I need to remap the num enter key to enter in the terminal. I'm using openSUSE with GNOME and Wayland. Num enter doesn't work when I use ssh. From the factory, my laptop's regular enter key works like num enter

Comment: You say that the key doesn't work when you use ssh. Does it work outside of ssh? Also what behavior do you expect out of this key? Please elaborate

Comment: Yes, the terminal on my system seems to allow the use of num enter, which cannot be said about the server terminal.  I just want the enter key on my laptop to work like a regular enter key, not like num enter.  It looks like reassigning keys in the graphical environment is different from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this per-shell with a line in either ~/.inputrc or your ~/.zshrc depending on which shell you're using.
Grab the keycode for your num enter key by running `showkey -a` and pressing num enter, and then grabbing the short value it gives you that's located to the left of the hexademical that appears

After that add one of these lines, depending on the file.
For ~/.zshrc, add this:
`bindkey 'key' accept-line`(replace "key" with the keycode for the key you want to rebind, while keeping the quotation marks)

For ~/.inputrc:
`"key": accept-line`(once again, replace the word key itself with  the keycode you want, but keep the quotation marks)

Comment: I couldn't find a package with the `showcode` command anywhere. However, I added the line `bindkey '^M' accept-line` to the `~/.zshrc` file, then `source ~/.zshrc`, but it didn't help.

Comment: im sorry, i made a typo, the command is “showkey” not showcode

Comment: Here is the output of my enter:  `^M  13   0015   0x0d` . Which value exactly should I use? 0015 does not work, nor does ^M.

Comment: After looking at the output of the bindkeys command, I noticed that the `"^M" accept-line` assignment was already there. And if I press CTRL+M, then everything works. Why then does my key, which is defined as ^M, not work? The system terminal that accepts my enter uses bash, while the server uses zsh